# How to apply border in nav-pills when using nav-stacked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I apply the border on the left side (or right as the case may be) when I use nav-stacked in nav-pills?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="states" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>States</h3>
        <p>States tab</p>
      </div>
      <div id="subs" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Subscriptions</h3>
        <p>Subscriptions tab</p>
      </div>
      <div id="comments" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        <p>Comments tab</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="myTabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#states" data-toggle="tab">
          States
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#subs" data-toggle="tab">
          Subscriptions
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">
          Comments
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it like that and tweak it around according to your needs. Hope, it helps. If you want it to apply on all instead of just the active one you need to modify `.nav-pills> .active` to `.nav-pills> *`

```css
.nav-pills>li {
  border-left:2px solid #444444;
}

.nav-pills>.active {
  border-right: 2px solid #444444;
  border-top: 2px solid #444444;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
  border-left:none;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="states" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>States</h3>
        <p>States tab</p>
      </div>
      <div id="subs" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Subscriptions</h3>
        <p>Subscriptions tab</p>
      </div>
      <div id="comments" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        <p>Comments tab</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="myTabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#states" data-toggle="tab">
          States
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#subs" data-toggle="tab">
          Subscriptions
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">
          Comments
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated- Added other borders to make it look like nav-tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend. I need to clarify that the edge should look like when using nav-tabs (ignore the color): https://www.bootply.com/gjjXWz6eOZ
Cheerz

Comment: Can you maybe like take a screenshot of how you want these nav-pills edges exactly? Because Im not really getting the idea. Edit the screenshot in paint or something to add the edges where you want them

Comment: Updated, is that what you want it to look like?

Comment: I need the stacked navs to be as in this example: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/nP8E7 The only problem of the previous example is that it is not responsive. Currently my design is https://imgur.com/a/ZzolC without borders on the navs. Cheerz